# Asp.net ConnectionString in secure way

Tags: c#, asp.net, security

I could not get a satisfactory answer to my question on the google, they are:

- How secure ConnectionString is over the HttpRequest?
- Is using ConnectionString in web.config file more secure than using in any specific aspx page?
- And how to secure ConnectionString for highly secure website?

I'm just curious to know about this.

Comment: Are you sending connection strings over HTTP?

Comment: `web.config` is safe, IIS will not serve this file to the client.

Comment: It makes sense why you didn't find any useful results... your google queries were no more understandable than your question here. What do you mean by _secure_ and what does that have to do with HttpRequest or an ASPX website?

Comment: what do you mean ? the connection string is not send as it is, you mean for local database or from connect to other computer... can you give some example and be more precise

Comment: What do you mean with "How secure ConnectionString is over the HttpRequest"? How secure is the connection to the server over HTTP or how secure is to transmit a ConnnectionString over HTTP?

Comment: I found about securing connectionString in MSDN(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that's why I came into this issue. something like encrypting ConnectionString, but it was quite complicated.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma: Note that encrypting might secure your web.config more but only for people who have anyway access to read it on the server. No configuration file will be sent via network.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Ok. you mean whoever can access the application on server, this encryption or securing technique is for them, right? And hacker or any third person can't see my ConnectionString's username or password? If so, my problem has been solved.

Comment: @AshwiniVerma: Specify _hacker_. If this person belongs to the group which _has read access_ on your server, your problem might not be solved ;)

Comment: @ClaudioRedi: storing plain text conn string in a web config is not drastically secure, as config file can be downloaded (through hundreds of vulnerabilities) remotely and read directly as plain text. "as oleksii said in below comments"

Comment: @TimSchmelter: so, do you think I should go for encryption technique if my website need to be more secure?

Comment: That can help but it might be easier (if applicable) to use integrated security and not store username/password in cleartext at all. More important is to secure your network and server in general.(firewalls,service-packs/patches,minimum software,separate db and webserver, closed db-ports, ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can encrypt the conenction string inside the webconfig, here is an article from Microsoft about this topic : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.80).aspx

If you sending the connectionstring over a channel its not more secure than the channel. For example sending the connectionstring over HTTP and it will be just plain text, HTTPS and it will be encrypted, over FTP just plan text, and so on...

If you have a webapplication in a shared hosted environment you should be worried about that the provider maybe get hacked.

So just keep the connection string inside the web.config and encrypt it and don't send it around on internet ;-)

Comment: in local connection you do not even need to encrypt it, just select Integrated Security=True <add name="OneConnection" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=TheDB;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />  Even if you read that, you have nothing to do it.

Comment: @Aristos: but it is not local server.

Answer (score 4):

The connection strings are safe in the web.config. They are very secure unless you print them out on the web requests.

Comment: Could you explain a bit here, you probably meant something more, as I am sure you are well aware that storing plain text conn string in a web config is not drastically secure, as config file can be downloaded (through hundreds of vulnerabilities) remotely and read directly as plain text

Comment: @oleksii: yes you are right. that's why looking forward to now more about this.

Answer (score 3):

Nice project on CodePlex [Encrypt/Decrypt Connection string](http://webconfigenc.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few methods to secure your connectionstring like

1. Encrypt your connectionstring and save it in webconfig
2. Encrypt your connectionstring and save it in windows registry

Its best to save connectionstring in webconfig to be used as a single point of use for whole application.

Answer (score 2):

> How secure ConnectionString is over the HttpRequest?

It is a string. It is only as secure as the connection is, so, normally not at all. This is assuming you are *sending* the connection string details over a `HttpRequest`. If this is not the case and your connection string is used in the `web.config`, it is as safe as the file itself and IIS are.

> Is using ConnectionString in web.config file more secure than using in any specific aspx page?

No.

> And how to secure ConnectionString for highly secure website?

Normally, one uses integrated security (windows authentication) to avoid hard coding of a username and password. Additionally, you can encrypt the configuration section, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx) (RSA) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) (DPAPI).

Answer (score 0):

**How secure ConnectionString is over the HttpRequest?**

Do you send the connection string over http request ? Really ? what scenario it is ? Ususally only requests for a webpage travels thru http request and the response as well.  Connectionstring is something your code internally use to access data and it stays in your server.

**Is using ConnectionString in web.config file more secure than using in any specific aspx page?**

Think about maintainability. If you put your connection string in a class, you have to rebuild your app when you have to change your connection string . If some body has access to your folder where you have your files, they can use a disassembler to see what is in your dlls.

**And how to secure ConnectionString for highly secure website?**

You can encrypt connection string in web.config. check this link 
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/304638/Encrypt-or-Decrypt-Connection-Strings-in-web-confi

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions in turn:

- `How secure ConnectionString is over the HttpRequest?`

You should never have to pass your connection string over HTTP; what usually happens is a user makes a request, your site processes the request including connecting to the database, and returns the result to the client. Connection String should not be sent over HTTP in this scenario.

- `Is using ConnectionString in web.config file more secure than using in any specific aspx page?`

Depends on what you do with the connection string - if you ever write it out to the client then it's never going to be secure! The connection string is usually placed into config for reusability purposes; embedding it on every page makes for a lot more maintainance and potential bugs.

- `And how to secure ConnectionString for highly secure website?`

You can encrypt the connection - so it is never stored as plain text, or use Windows Authentication so you never need a password. This is supported by ASP.Net as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx).