# you can see SQL connection string username and password in compiled DLL when you store connection string in app.config

Tags: vb.net, connection-string

I have a .net class library that compiles to dll. in this project I have dataset. under my project - settings.settings I keep my connection string. it is SQL authentication. 

Then when I did a search using wingrep for username and password, low and behold, I can see it clearly in clear text in the DLL. 

is there a way to have the dll not easily readable using notepad? 
is having connection string under settings.settings not the best idea?
please advise?

thank you

not sure if this will serve my purpose? 
http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/10926_3500906_2/Encrypt-Connection-Strings-in-VS-2005-config-Files.htm I'll test and update tomorrow.

Comment: use windows authentication

Comment: unfortunately I inherited this medium systems that it is going to be a battle trying to convert this to integrated security. is there a workaround ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this that I think that will serve my goal. indeed it is for winforms and my application is a DLL. but it should be similar enough that it will work

[How to securely store a connection string in a WinForms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606892/how-to-securely-store-a-connection-string-in-a-winforms-application)

Answer (score 0):

How are you deploying this app?

If it's a web app, then anyone who can own your system to the level of opening the DLL in a text editor can probably get into the database already and it won't matter what you do with the connection string.

If it's a desktop app, then the suggestion to use Windows authentication is probably the best. If that's not an option, then just make sure each user has their own username/password and store it securely outside the DLL.

Comment: Securely outside the dll = NOT GOOD IDEA. Could you elaborate securely outside of the dll?